# Chrome doesn't honor row height if rowspan is present

Tags: css, google-chrome, html-table

I want to make a table with a cell that spans on two rows. The second row must have the height size as minimum as possible. Example:

html:

```
<table>
    <tr id="row-1">
        <td>
            1st row
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            a <br />
            a <br />
            a <br />
            a <br />
            a <br />
            a <br />
            a <br />
            a <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row-2">
        <td>
            2nd row
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
td
{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#row-2
{
    height: 1px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xp7vz/

It works on Firefox (19.0.2). On Chromium (25.0.1364.160), the row with the minimum height is the first one!

EDIT: The problem is caused by this bug: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=78724

How can I hack it with CSS? Currently I'm using JS, setting the 1st row height equal to the height of the rowspan cell minus the height of the second row.

Comment: I'm intrigued. What are you using your table for?

Comment: It's only a table for describing items of a little game. Example: http://grinns-tale.wikia.com/wiki/Leprechaun_Hat . Since the table can be ajax-loaded by other pages, I want it as small as possible.

Comment: I like your js solution, actually, but I'm assuming you want to make sure it displays properly for those who don't have it enabled, right? You could try putting the last column in its own table and making it display directly below the first, but that still isn't quite proper use of tables.

Comment: Yes, I want to use JS as little as possible. Now I'm trying to use a floating div instead of a rowspan. The problem is I need to float the table at the bottom. If the floating div is small in height, the table go outside the its container div, even if I added a clearing div: http://jsfiddle.net/26e75/3/ Must I open another answer?

Comment: Another thing to consider is how many people use Chrome and how many people don't have JS enabled. There are a lot of people who use Chrome (it's my favorite browser), and there is a significant number of  people who don't have JS enabled, but the number of people who fit into both categories is probably pretty slim. Also, since your target audience is players of an online game, practically all of them will probably have JS enabled. I'd be surprised if even 1% won't see it properly. And even so, they can still see it, it just won't be AS pretty. I'd consider sticking with your JS solution.

Comment: @knoell8504: The fact is that JS must wait the DOM is ready to work well, so you'll see a deformed table until the page is ready. By the way, I prefer Firefox. It's more slow, but it's more standards-compliant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found: the trick is to put another table inside a cell of the table with the non-rowspan content, remove the rowspan from the other cell and set the outer and inner table height to 100%. Horrible but effective.

HTML:

```
<table id="outer"><tbody><tr>
    <td>
        <table id="inner"><tbody>
            <tr id="row-1">
                <td>1st row</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row-2">
                <td>2nd row</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </td>
    <td>
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
        a<br />
    </td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

CSS:

```
#row-2 
{
    height: 1px;
}
#outer, #inner 
{
    height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xp7vz/3/

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Lucas Malor almost works.

It happens that **IE** doesn't respect table height=100% :(
For me solution was easy, I just set height in pixels, because I know height of first column.

Answer (score 0):

try `position:fixed`

it sort of works. http://jsfiddle.net/43CEX/

i think in general you want to use divs for this kind of work, since tables natively grow by their own

**update**

this http://jsfiddle.net/h4Ycj/

or this  http://jsfiddle.net/m7eqm/

Comment: Mmmmhh... no :-P Yes, the second row height fits its content, but the first row height doesn't fill the remaining table height. I'm using table because I must fill tabular data (with the exception of the cell with rowspan)

Comment: so you want the opposite of the original one.

Comment: ok so i have come up with these two solutions http://jsfiddle.net/h4Ycj/ and http://jsfiddle.net/m7eqm/

Comment: first one is from http://blog.myrdo.com/2010/02/chrome-bug-table-cell-height-and-rowspan/ (the last comment) and the second one is kind of a cheap solution. :)

Comment: @LucasMalor hope these help.

Comment: i just saw your edit as you were using js as well. from the blog link i posted, i am afraid it is not possible to achieve it in pure CSS.

Comment: Thank you anyway :) I hope someone would find an obscure CSS trick :-D