# Get two divs to fill up remaining height

Tags: css, html-table

I want to achieve this kind of layout:

```
|---| |------------|
|   | |      b     |
| a | |____________|
|   | |------------|
|___| |______c_____|
```

Code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="leftSide">a</td>
        <td class="rightSide">
            <div class="mainContent">b</div>
            <div class="bottomContent">c</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Where box `a`'s height should resize fit both `b` and `c` if their total ends up taller than itself. This currently works because `.rightSide` is set to `display: table`, with divs `b` and `c` set to `display: table-row`.

However, if `a`'s content causes it to be taller than the right side, said right side's heights stay the same--the containing `td` resizes, but its contents don't. I want `b` (`.mainContent`) to fill its remaining height. How would I do this?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2RExz/)

Comment: First things first. Why are you using `tables`?

Comment: yea it looks like rowspan would do the job lol

Comment: @MelanciaUK to resize the height of both the left and right side equally, probably

Comment: @MelanciaUK Sure tables aren't always the best idea, but they work. If you've got a better idea, add it as an answer.

Comment: @Twon-ha yes, that's the reason here, but it's not an excuse to use `tables` for layout. They should be used just to list down tabular data.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire I gave just my opinion, which is the same of the majority. Your answer, based on the OP markup, is correct. To answer on a different way, I would need to re-design the whole thing, and that's not the point here.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Haha, I agree that I won't usually use tables for this, but I am this time because this structure is going to be repeated across multiple rows as a list--so using tables in that situation seems like it'd be the least hassle.

Comment: @idlackage got your point now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`rowspan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td#attr-rowspan) attribute. This will let you make one `td` span multiple rows.

Try something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="leftSide" rowspan="2">a</td>
        <td class="rightSide">b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="rightSide">c</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/q9f3F/)

Comment: Thanks for the simple solution. Question though: Right now, `c` takes up the remaining height. How would I get `b` to do it? http://jsfiddle.net/q9f3F/1/

Comment: I think you're looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/q9f3F/2/). Yes, it is nasty, but it does work. Credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15536718/1721527

Comment: Interesting how that's essentially the exact same thing I had before, except with a real table instead of CSS properties--but now I see why it works. I was just missing `height: 100%` on `.rightSide`. Thanks!