# Div in table rowspan not using full height

Tags: css, html-table

I've got a pretty regular HTML `<table>` with one cell that spans multiple rows via `rowspan`. Inside of this cell I've got a `<div>` that I want to occupy the entire height of the cell but for the life of me I can't seem to figure it out. It seems similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449185/chrome-doesnt-honor-row-height-if-rowspan-is-present) which mentions [this Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=78724) but also seems so simple that maybe I'm just not thinking clearly.

Here's a stripped down version of my HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="a" rowspan="2"><div>A</div></td>
        <td class="b"><div>B</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="c"><div>C</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
td
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
td.a div
{
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bG5WF/). And here's what I'm getting and what I'm trying to get:

[image]

What's really weird is if I use Chrome's inspector to change the `<div>` to `display: inline-block` and then set it back to `display: block` it actually looks pretty much exactly how I want it to.

(And no, switching away from a table isn't an option for this project, there's other code not shown that requires that.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Option 1

Simply add `overflow:auto;` to your `div` CSS

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bG5WF/1/)

```
td
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
td.a div
{
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 100%;overflow:auto;
}
```

### Option 2

Alternatively you'll need to define the height of your table in order for the child to be able to calculate what its 100% is 100% of.

### Option 3

The only other way would be to set `position:relative` on the `td` elements then `position:absolute` for the child `div`

Comment: Option 1 it is! Thank you!

Comment: Several years later, Option 1 no longer seems to work in latest Chrome. Your demo fiddle renders just like the "Actual" screenshot from initial question.